# It's slow to send email by the default EmailBackend of django 1.11 using Microsoft business email account

Tags: django, email, smtplib

I'm using the default EmailBackend of Django 1.11, I just simply called the send_mail method as the ref. document said, here are my settings of the SMTP server:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'oalite@xxx.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[OALite Admin]'
```

Here is my log outputted by smtplib.py:

```
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'SG2PR06CA0180.outlook.office365.com Hello [85.203.47.85]\nSIZE 157286400\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nAUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2\n8BITMIME\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8'
send: 'AUTH LOGIN b2FBaXRl0GlyaXhpLmNvb0==\r\n'
reply: b'334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6\r\n'
reply: retcode (334); Msg: b'UGFzc3dvcmQ6'
send: 'QEdBbH1w0DJuSwY=\r\n

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> halted here for about 15s to wait the reply <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

reply: b'235 2.7.0 Authentication successful target host BLUPR04MB420.namprd04.prod.outlook.com\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: b'2.7.0 Authentication successful target host BLUPR04MB420.namprd04.prod.outlook.com'
send: 'mail FROM:<oalite@xxx.com> size=943\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.1.0 Sender OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'2.1.0 Sender OK'
send: 'rcpt TO:<user.foo@xxx.com>\r\n'
reply: b'250 2.1.5 Recipient OK\r\n'
```

Please note that I was using the business email account of Microsoft, the domain xxx.com actually is our company domain name.

I have no idea why it took 15s to authenticate, it's very fast to send emails using the outlook desktop app with the same account. Is it faster to use Exchange protocol then to use SMTP protocol?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what is your question? Why it is that slow? What you can do about it? Authentication at microsofts service obviously takes 15 seconds at the moment... :) Your question seems to include your current password base64 encoded - which is a bad idea as one can easily decode it. You should remove this part and change the password.

Comment: @dahrens Thanks for your advice, I have modified my question. The password and email address are faked :P So it's normal to take 15s to authenticate my account under SMTP protocol? or I missed something to speed up authentication process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options for quickly sending outgoing mail from views, when authentication is slow:

- Use [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to offload mail sending to an offline task.
- Install a local (forwarding) mail server on your host.  On linux this can be accomplished easily with `postfix`.  You can configure the mail server to connect to your business email account.
- Both :-)

There seems to be a [REST API to connect to outlook.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial) - so you can also write [your own mail backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-email-backend) for sending mail via HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try the ways you mentioned! The REST API is slow as well, it's always slow to connect to the Microsoft Service from china except the exchange protocol.

Comment: I installed the Postfix to forward the emails, it’s pretty fast now, thanks a lot!